# Empty MFC dialog has LNK2019 unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc

thanks for reading my post. 
I have some C++ experience, but I'm new to visual C++. I was working on a project that was created by someone else. The program is a MFC dialog based. At first, everything was fine. However, from some point, every time I debug the program, I got LNK2019 error.I though I might have accidentally changed something. So I repaired the VS on my PC, and created a new MFC dialog project(files and codes were generated by Wizard). The strange thing is, every time I debug the new program without changing anything, I still get the same error.

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall CWnd::DoDataExchange(class CDataExchange *)const " (?DoDataExchange@CWnd@@MBEXPAVCDataExchange@@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall CMFCApplication2Dlg::DoDataExchange(class CDataExchange *)" (?DoDataExchange@CMFCApplication2Dlg@@MAEXPAVCDataExchange@@@Z) D:\TWS Client\MFCApplication2\MFCApplication2\MFCApplication2Dlg.obj    MFCApplication2

Comment: Find the function `CWnd::DoDataExchange` in your project and make sure its source file is compiled.

Comment: Basically, Your compiler couldnt link your generated obj . If you have changed your settings then need Check your 1.Calling Conversion 2.Libs as well.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs. The problem has been solved. I have noticed that I had two VS installed on my PC, the older version hadn't been completely uninstalled in the last time I reinstalled my VS. And in the error log, I found that there were some lines mention the old VS folderpath. This time I completely uninstalled everything, after I install again, my project runs perfectly again.